# How do i add a "." between the letters of the initials?

Tags: python, function

Create a function called initials that takes in a persons names and then returns the initials. You should pass the names using **args.

For example for James Marshall Hendrix it should return J.M.H.

Or, for John Ronald Reuel Tolkien it should return J.R.R.T (one *arg to rule them all).

My outputs are JMH AND JRRT But i need to output them as the ones above.

```
def initials(*args):
    result = "" 
    for word in args:
        result += word[0].upper()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(initials("James", "Marshall", "Hendrix")) # should print the return value of "J.M.H"
  print(initials("John", "Ronald", "Reuel", "Tolkien")) # should print the return value of "J.R.R.T"
```

Comment: Don't use repeated `str` concatenation, make a `list` of the initials, then can `'.'.join` on it. It's more efficient (in a meaningless way when talking about initials for a single name), and it solves the problem of avoiding putting a `.` at the end of the sequence for free.

Comment: Try the python [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) method.

Comment: `'.'.join(map(operator.itemgetter(0), args))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
def initials(*args):
    result = []
    for word in args:
        result.append(word[0])
    return ".".join(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(initials("James", "Marshall", "Hendrix"))  # should print the return value of "J.M.H"
    print(initials("John", "Ronald", "Reuel", "Tolkien"))  # should print the return value of "J.R.R.T"
```

Here is the fixed code, we store the result in a list instead of a string like how you did before, and we join the list with `.` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can compact all that with a list comprehension:

```
def initials(*args):
    return '.'.join([n[0] for n in args])

print(initials("James", "Marshall", "Hendrix")) 
# J.M.H
print(initials("John", "Ronald", "Reuel", "Tolkien"))
# J.R.R.T
```

Edit: (thanks to azro): you can simplify it even further using a generator; it will be slower though (read ShadowRanger's very interesting comment below):

```
    return '.'.join(n[0] for n in args)
```

Comment: @azro: Secrets of CPython implementation: It's actually faster with the listcomp than the genexpr. The first thing `str.join` does is convert anything that's not a `list` or `tuple` to a `list`, so if you pass it a genexpr, it just exhausts it immediately (but in a slightly slower fashion than a listcomp would, thanks to generator overhead); if you pass it the result of a faster listcomp, it does no additional work. Usually a genexpr is the way to go, `str.join` is an exception to that general rule. It does this so it can fully precompute the final length, and allocate just once.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can just add a "." when you take the first letter and then you can just return it without the first character anyway this method can
implement in any other programming language.

```
def initials(*args):
    result = "" 
    for word in args:
            result +="."+ word[0].upper()
    return result[1:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(initials("James", "Marshall", "Hendrix")) 
  print(initials("John", "Ronald", "Reuel", "Tolkien"))
```